# TensorBoard not shown all epochs?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

Below the code for using the tensorboard. How does it come that im not shown all epoch_accuraty and epoch_loss? in the picture below you see how it looks like.

```
log_dir = ".\\tensorflow_logs\\test\\" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='binary_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=1, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

[tensorboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcmXw.png)

Does someone know what is the solution or problem?

Comment: I've run your code and everything went OK. Maybe there is a mistake in another part. Please show the entire code.